# Recuperar os acentos de uma string com PHP

Tags: php, string

Estou usando urls amigáveis e para gerar o link, estou usando dessa forma:

```
$string = $jm->NomeCategoria; // retorna roupa de verão
$hifen = preg_replace('/[ -]+/' , '-' , $string); // incluo o hífen
$acentos = preg_replace( '/[`^~\'"]/', null, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $hifen)); // retiro as acentuações
```

Com esses comandos ele retorna: **roupa-de-verao**. Só que preciso recuperar em outra página a *string* correta **roupa de verão**, pois preciso fazer a verificação no banco de dados. Consegui retirar o hífen e colocar os espaços, as é possível "devolver" as acentuações de uma *string*?

Comment: Você não pode passar passar duas váriaveis ? a original e o resultado com hifen e sem acentos ?

Comment: Pois é... pensei também em criar na base de dados, na hora de criar as categorias, mais um campo chamado **url** e na hora de cadastrar, gerar o link amigável e depois recuperar... mas se tivesse um meio mais simples....

Comment: Eu acho que não tem como, a não ser que você crie um dicionário pras suas categorias, mas acabaria virando na mesma coisa que ter mais um campo no BD

Comment: Pq vc não salva a variavel "roupa de verão" numa session assim 
`$_SESSION['url'] = $jm->NomeCategoria;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essencialmente não tem como. Até teria, mas a solução é tão complexa que não compensa. Teria que ter outros mecanismos para resolver isto, manter os acentos, ter um código, ter uma tabela com e sem acento, tem várias formas de resolver.

Dependendo do que precisa pode pesquisar no banco de dados de forma insensitiva, que costuma ser até a forma mais correta, assim ele ignora os acentos na busca. Não serve para todos os casos, mas acho a solução mais apropriada.